# Issue with nesting quotes while pushing event GTM

Tags: javascript, jquery, quotes, google-tag-manager, double-quotes

I'm pushing events to GTM in `onclick` event of anchor tag the problem here is while getting the data through jQuery i'm unable use the quote(single or double) as it is breaking the code. I also tried escaping the quotes with `\(slash)` and using XML `&quot;` but still unable sort out the issue. Here is my code

```
    <a title="Comprar" class="btn-pdp-bag"
        onclick=" dataLayer.push({
          'event':addToCart,
          'ecommerce':{
              'remove':{
                  'products':[{'name':'Playera Polo',
                              'id':'123456' ,
                              'price':'1340.0',                                                     
                              'category':$('#ancestorLbl').text(),
                              'subcategory':$('#breadCrumbLbl').text(),
                              'variant': $('div').find('[data-id=\"ddldynamiccolor\"] span').text(),                                  'quantity':'1'
                           }]
                        }
                       }
                       }); href="#"> send Gtm </a>
```

I need to send the data with quote around but if i place quote for

```
$('#ancestorLbl').text()
```

it is considered as string if i place double quote `onclick` is getting closed.

same issue with

```
$('div').find('[data-id=\"ddldynamiccolor\"] span').text()
```

in this case in addition to quotes around i need to use quotes for data selector too.
please suggest me how i can fix this issue here is the  [link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m49pdq44/).Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your issue arises as you are attempting to put a large amount of code into an inline function call.  Whilst it is perfectly achievable with a certain amount of escaping characters and removing whitespace/newlines, I feel it would be wrong not to suggest the more elegant solutions available to you.

**Option A - call a function**

Create a function with all your code in it and call it from your onclick event.

**Option B - dynamically bind your code to the element**

As you're already using jQuery you could use the on() function to bind to this element.  This would require you to give the link a unique identifier (unless you want multiple links to fire the correct code).

So give you link a unique identifier and strip out the onclick:

```
<a id="comprar" title="Comprar" class="btn-pdp-bag" href="#"> send Gtm </a>
```

Now dynamically bind your code to this link when the click event occurs

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#comprar').on('click', function(){
    dataLayer.push({
      'event':addToCart,
      'ecommerce':{
        'remove':{
          'products':[{'name':'Playera Polo',
                              'id':'123456' ,
                              'price':'1340.0',                                                     
                              'category':$('#ancestorLbl').text(),
                              'subcategory':$('#breadCrumbLbl').text(),
                              'variant': $('div').find('[data-id="ddldynamiccolor"] span').text(),
                              'quantity':'1'
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**Option C - Keep it inline**

If you really need to keep it inline, firstly, you should question why.  Then you should eradicate all newlines (plus whitespace to keep it neat but this isn't absolutely necessary.) and use the following:

```
    <a title="Comprar" class="btn-pdp-bag" onclick=" dataLayer.push({'event':'addToCart','ecommerce':{'remove':{'products':[{'name':'Playera Polo','id':'123456','price':'1340.0','category':$('#ancestorLbl').text(),'subcategory':$('#breadCrumbLbl').text(),'variant': $('div').find('[data-id=\'ddldynamiccolor\'] span').text(),'quantity':'1'}]}}});" href="#"> send Gtm </a>
```

It's completely up to you which method you use but I recommend Option B as its a bit more elegant to do it this way.  In this method you completely abstract the javascript functionality away from the HTML and therefore any changes you need to make only require a change to the JS.  You can also put this in a separate file and include it on your page.

Comment: thanks for quick reply dmpg_tom. But  for me it is mandatory to push event from inline call is there any way to fix this issue with inline events as i used above.

Comment: I've added option C for you which shows how to do it.  You absolutely need to be questioning why you need to keep this inline.  even if you only have access to the HTML (and no linked script files) you should be using Option A instead.  Option C is last resort but i really can't think of a scenario when this may occur.

Comment: it may sound strange but i have use inline push. I think removing the spaces and new lines makes no effect.Value from  $('#breadCrumbLbl').text() is being considered as variable and i'm getting undefined error so we must use quotes around.

Comment: good point, i notice you were using double quotes in the data-id attribute selector.  You need to use escaped single quotes, you cannot use double quotes in inline code - even when escaped.  plus you need to use single quotes around the addToCart event name.  I've tested this my end now and seems to work fine.

Comment: I had already updated the code but also, you really should ahve a go yourself and try and debug (based on my suggestions) - just giving you the code doesn't help you learn.  Code is now correct in the option C above

Comment: nope. **option c** u have suggested will only make the code inline but it wont resolve the quotes issue I'm facing **adding quotes around the value coming from  $('#ancestorLbl').text()**. I'm working on it to resolve the issue

Comment: I don't believe you need to add quotes. They purely denote that the content in the quotes is a hard coded string. By using the jquery statement you are creating a string, this no need for quotes